# When to use Spring's CassandraTemplate vs CassandraRepository

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data

Normally I'll create all my entity classes and then a separate repo class for each entity where I throw all my CQL queries. However I was wondering in what instance one would use the CassandraTemplate over a repo class? Thanks!